# shared_pointer best practices

Tags: c++

A smart pointer is used in this small routine to spare the caller the hassle of `free()`ing the returned buffer (and protect against his failure to do so) :

```cpp
char* toupper(const string& s){
  string ret(s.size(), char());
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    ret[i] = (s[i] <= 'z' && s[i] >= 'a') ? s[i]-('a'-'A') : s[i];
  return (char*) memcpy(
   chkedAlloc(1+ret.size(),*std::make_shared<char*>(nullptr)),
   ret.c_str(), 1+ret.size()
  );
}
```

`chkedAlloc(n,A)` returns `new A[n]` after catching `std::bad_alloc`s.

This looks like a textbook use of smart pointers to make life easier & safer?

Do you see any fault with/possible improvement in this code?

**improvements/comments:**

- Return a string. It's destructor frees the associated storage when it goes out of scope.
- This is a case of "shared_ptr as a last resort". "shared" is more expensive than "unique".
- If you're thinking that :

  - a shared_ptr is thread-safe
  - a unique_ptr can't be passed to others

stop believing that. Owners can deal `unique_ptr`s, but one at a time can hold ownership.

- Consider the standard template algo std::transform.
- Don't use use `std::string` in your example code, prefer `int`, to avoid all kinds of side-discussions.

```cpp
unique_ptr<char*> toupper(const string& s){
  string ret(s.size(), char());
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    ret[i] = (s[i] <= 'z' && s[i] >= 'a') ? s[i]-('a'-'A') : s[i];
  char *p = new char[1+ret.size()]; // try/catch(std::bad_alloc)
  return make_unique<char*>((char*) memcpy(p, ret.c_str(), 1+ret.size()));
}
void f() { string s = "hello"; .. 
  { char* p = *toupper(s); // this scope now owns the pointer
  } // leaving the scope: allocated memory on the heap freed by smart pointer
..
}
```

Comment: This is an even better case to return a `std::string`.

Comment: Take a look into [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for an easier way to transform a `string`. The example used at the bottom of the linked documentation page will give you a simple one-liner.

Comment: What is `chkedAlloc`? That return statement is undecipherable to me. And I see a lot of code in a day. I can't think of any way `*std::make_shared<char*>(nullptr)` can do anything helpful.

Comment: The use of `make_shared()` in this code makes no sense. It is allocating an owned `char*` pointer (not a `char[]` buffer!) that doesn't point anywhere. `memcpy()` needs allocated memory to copy to. What does `chkedAlloc()` actually do? This looks like very dangerous code to me. Especially since you mention `free()`, which `shared_ptr` does not use, but does `chkedAlloc()` really require it?

Comment: "shared_pointer best practices" simple: avoid using them at all unless absolutely necessary. Designs with clear-cut ownership relations are simpler and cleaner in general. Also, while `std::unique_ptr` is perfectly fine, `std::shared_ptr` has some unexpected overhead involved (due to its thread safety obligations)

Comment: @Frank the overhead is atomic increment/decrement, it does not ensure thread-safety of the data. Don't quote me on that, but some compilers also should be able to replace atomic with normal counter if program isn't multithreaded, although the gain seems to be minimal.

Comment: @Kaihaku I'm not saying that shared_ptr ensures thread safety, just that it has certain obligations to fullfill, hence the use of the atomic counters.

Comment: user4581301: I know of std::transform. I'm currently limited to C++14, unfortenetly. François & Remy: updated question to explain chkedAlloc (thought its name was explicit enough)

Comment: You're in luck then! `std::transform` was added to C++ back in the C++98 standard, which due to the stupidity of 2 digit time stamps (something we should have known in 1998 with the looming Y2K crisis coming) came before c++14.

Comment: Your description of `chkedAlloc` makes it sound like a possible bug factory. What does it do if it catches the `bad_alloc`? Throw a new exception? Log and rethrow the `bad_alloc`? Try again (and probably fail)? Return a pointer to something that it didn't allocate?

Comment: Frank: you're right, but I wanted a use-case for smart pointers. toupper() returns an allocated char* to the caller, so this pointer has to be *shared* (with caller), unique_ptr won't do, I think.

Comment: Strings aren't a good use case. Consider a class with some virtual methods. `unique_ptr` is a great way to own virtual data, which can't be stored on the stack. Strings are just messy in general, and that's why `std::string` is its own type and not an alias for `std::unique_ptr<char*>`. `std::shared_ptr` is a last-resort and shouldn't be used unless the *only* alternative is raw pointers.

Comment: You can return a `unique_ptr` to the caller such that the caller will take ownership. Usually much cheaper than `shared_ptr`, but more importantly it expresses that there is only one owner of the allocation. When I see a `shared_ptr` I read it as "someone else has an equal ownership stake in this object. I have only partial control over its lifespan."

Comment: user4581301: I didn't know that ! `chkedAlloc` simply exit()'s on `bad_alloc`. I'm learning through your comments (thx), but both of these points are not the focus of my question.

Comment: user4581301: just tested with unique_ptr. You're absolutely right. In my mind, unique somehow meant "won't relinquish"! While unique actually means 1 owner (at a time), but ownership *can* be passed around.

Comment: `exit` is a good-ish option because `bad_alloc` usually translates to "You're <expletive deleted>ed. Time to start over." But allowing the exception to propagate is generally safer. `exit` ends the program with less clean-up. There is no [stack unwinding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exceptions-and-stack-unwinding-in-cpp?view=msvc-160), so some destructors will not be run.  If one of those destructors has a real-world effect like moving a robot arm back to a safe position, it won't happen. A thrown exception will unwind the stack, and everything will be cleaned up as expected.

Answer (score 1):

One major flaw in this code is here:

```
*std::make_shared<char*>(nullptr)
```

makes no sense whatsoever. It is just a convoluted and expensive way of obtaining a null pointer. The whole expression can be replaced with `nullptr`, so the smart pointer in this function is of no help to anyone.

It is in fact the newest iteration of the persistent error people keep making over and over and over and over again.

In C:

```
Foo foo = *(Foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));
```

In C++:

```
Foo foo = *new Foo;
```

and now this:

```
Foo foo = *std::make_shared<Foo>();
```

All of the above are instances of the same bug. Don't do this. Dynamic allocation returns you a pointer so that you can **store** it somewhere. The pointer is **not** meant to be immediately dereferenced and forgotten.

Since the smart pointer in the function body, contrary to the expectations, is useless and doesn't save the caller any hassle whatsoever, the signature

```
char* toupper(const string& s){
```

is a bug. It should be

```
std::string toupper (const std::string& s) {
```

and the `return` statement should simply return `ret`. The whole

```
(char*) memcpy(
   chkedAlloc(1+ret.size(),*std::make_shared<char*>(nullptr)),
   ret.c_str(), 1+ret.size()
  );
```

isn't doing anything useful.

Finally, the loop

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    ret[i] = (s[i] <= 'z' && s[i] >= 'a') ? s[i]-('a'-'A') : s[i];
```

can be rewritten as

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), ret.begin(), 
               static_cast<int (*)(int)>(::toupper));
```

(your own function name would conflict with just `::toupper` so you need to specify the type)

Another option is

```
std::string toupper(std::string s){       // yes, yes, pass by value
   for (auto& c: s) c = std::toupper(c);
   return s;
}
```

Note `::toupper` and `std::toupper` are two different functions.

Comment: If the function allocates a `int* p=new int[35]`, makes a `q=unique_ptr<int*>(p)` and returns `p`, what happens to the allocated memory when the caller is done with the returned `int*` ?

Comment: This is an entirely different question. If you want to ask a question, please press the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Side note:: `toupper` (and the rest of its ctype friends) takes an `int` for it's argument rather than a `char` so that it can better handle out-of-band signals like EOF. This has the unfortunate side effect of sign-extending any signed characters provided, potentially changing their value and causing chaos. Doesn't happen all that often, but if you get weird results, cast `c`  to `unsigned char` (`std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));`) just to be sure.

Comment: @WasfiJAOUAD aside from that, `q=unique_ptr<int*>(p)` is a type error. You need a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` to correctly hold `p`, but what you actually want is `std::vector<int> p(35);`